# Google Sheets: Column width

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am creating Spreadsheets via Java API and there seem to be no method for setting column width? According to this document: https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/rowcolumn - there seem to be a way via JSON:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateDimensionProperties": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "COLUMNS",
          "startIndex": 0,
          "endIndex": 1
        },
        "properties": {
          "pixelSize": 160
        },
        "fields": "pixelSize"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to set these via `SheetProperties` or `GridProperties`?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to set it using those properties. So I think the one  that was specified in the docs is the only available option as of now.
I checked [SpreadsheetProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#spreadsheetproperties) reference and 
[GridProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#gridproperties) as well and it does not mention what you're asking for.
If you plan to use

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId:batchUpdate
```

using Java, you can always resort to XHR.